# Combine n-grams in R

Tags: r

I would like to know how to combine n-grams.
For instance if we have the word bab, 
I would like to calculate one value based on the 
2gram(ba) = 2.969, 2gram(ab)=2.77.
I have 2 questions:
1. How is that done in theory?
2. In practice, is there an R implementaion of this that is efficient? 
I imagine the solution involves sparce matrices and if not carefully can be quite inefficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate one value" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`ngram`](https://github.com/wrathematics/ngram) package (the tokenization is handled by very efficient C code)

```
#install.packages("ngram")
library(ngram)

str <- "bab"
ng  <- ngram(splitter(str, split.char = TRUE))
```

Which gives:

```
> get.ngrams(ng)
#[1] "b a" "a b"
```

You could also get the frequency table by doing:

```
> get.phrasetable(ng)
#   ngrams freq prop
#1   b a     1  0.5
#2   a b     1  0.5
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I guess my question was not really clear. I know how to calculate the 2-grams from some text T. Given that "distribution", I want a score (e.g. probability) that a word (e.g. "bab") is drawn from that distribution.

Comment: @user2154457 Please provide a [MCVE]